# !Set.contains returning true though it contained values

Tags: apex, batch

[image]I have a Map value list that I am looking to check if it contained specific Id. I tried adding all map values to a set and the applying contains keyword. But either ways it returns false though I could see the values. Not sure what the issue is . Here is my code

```
// Map contact itm is of type <Id,Id> which stores contact Id and Item Id
for(Id keyId : contactitm.keyset()){
    for(Id pf : plist){                    // plist is list of all Items          
        Set<Id> val = new Set<Id>();
        val.addall(contactitm.values());
        if(!val.contains(pf)){             // this is always returning true '
            //perform logic
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want to use !val.contains(pf). It means val doesn't contain pf

Comment: I wanted to exclude if the value already existed. So I have logic as !val.contains() but that is always returning true even if the value existed already

Comment: Have you tried to use system.debug to print val and pf out before the if statement? Does that confirm your thinking?

Comment: Yep attached the print screen of logs. It shows the value in the list, but still entered the loop

Comment: N.B. Try renaming these variables such that they help expose your logic issue:  `contactItm` sb named `itemIdsByContactId`; `pList` sb named `allItemIds`; `val` sb named `allItemIdsWithContactId`, `pf` sb named `itemId`.